# Every time I open samba share folder in window he never ask different credentials

Tags: samba, centos7

I configure samba server in *CentOS 7*, and also samba server working good means samba share folder access in windows.

But problem is if i access share folder first time using `\\192.168.1.6\share` in window then he ask credentials to access samba. Every time when I open samba share folder using `\\192.168.1.6\share` from windows machine it use same samba user,  and never ask me new credentials.

I share number of samba folder for different samba user how to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you store entered credentials on Windows PC at first time? Can you provide in your question your `smb.conf` file listing?

Answer (score 2):

It may happen because of cached credentials on Windows clients. Try to disable caching, so your users will be forced to enter their login and password every time they try to get access to the share:

1. Run gpedit.msc
2. Check Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local 
   Policies\Security Options section
3. Find "Interactive Logon: Number of Previous Logins To Cache" (set this value to 0)

Hope it helps.